QReader - detect_and_decode opens a copy of the .exe
i have a python project where i use QReader to detect and decode a qr code from images i sent to the app. The problem is, the first time the project runs "qreader.detect_and_decode" it opens a copy of the .exe and i need to close it for the main program continues the process, until there its just not responding. I was using PySimpleGui and i thought that there was some bug between both, but i changed to QT Designer, and im working with .ui files, and the error
def readqrcode(self, counter,filename,folder,folder2):
        global parsed_data
        global matched_rows_filtered
        global fatura
        global flagFatura
        
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (400, 200))
        data = qreader.detect_and_decode(image=cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename, 0), cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR))

this is the funtion i call to decode the qr code and its here when the bug appears. By the way, it just happens in the first time i call the function, when i input more files, it works correctly.
I tried to change for QT Designer from PySimpleGui and i tried to move the qreader = QReader().

did you run in console to see error messages? Without error message and without minimal working codewe can't say what can make problem. At this moment we can only suggest to useprint()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables.

why do you open the same file again in detect_and_decode((image=cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename, 0), ...)? Why not use detect_and_decode(image=img, ...) ?

i simplified the code to just "data = qreader.detect_and_decode(image=cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename, 0), cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR))" instead of "all the 5 lines i had, but the error remains there. again, i already tried everything, and it's weird that the first time I click on the button that triggers the function, it encounters an error while detecting and decoding the QR code. However, on subsequent tries when adding more files to read the QR code, the program runs perfectly. And i dont get any error on console, it just opens again the window, i close it, and it returns to normal.

And i forgot to say, it only happens with .exe file generated with PyInstaller, when debugging it works fine

Its working, i was using Qreader that is a library that combines cv2 and pyzbar i guess, and i changed the code for pzybar, and it's much faster and works. Thanks for the help.
